# Adding a column or row to a csv file (matlab or cmd)

Tags: matlab, csv, awk, sed, append

This is a very common question I believe but I could not find an accurate enough answer. I need an answer either using MATLAB or using a simple enough command line prompt.
I have (many) .csv files in a directory which all are similar. Say the files look like,

```
1,2
3,4
```

I now want them to all look like

```
,c1,c2
t1,1,2
t2,3,4
```

I am not a 100% sure on how to format the entries correctly on StackExchange. There is no blank line between the first and secnd row. What I am doing is - I add a column "t1 t2..." and row "c1 c2..." to all the files. The very first cell in the file is blank. I need this done to all files in my directory. Of course the t1 t2 values and c1 c2 values should run for the entire size of the file.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to make a plot?  With column and row headers?  Can reformat your sample input and desired output?

Comment: No, not a plot. I need this specific format because another software (GAMS) uses this alone. I can reformat this on Excel but I have thousands of files in the folder.

Comment: @EdMorton you are exactly right. I don't know how to format in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    if( FNR==1 ) {
        close(fn); fn=FILENAME ".new"; printf OFS > fn

        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "c%d%s", i, (i!=NF) ? OFS:"\n" > fn
        }
    }
    print "t"FNR OFS $0 > fn
}
```

which does the following:

- `BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } - sets the field separators to`,`
- `FNR==1` - In the first line of each input file, `close(fn)` in case it's open, set `fn` equal to "your filename.new", then print a single leading `,`.  `FNR` is the line number in the current file.
- Also create the `c#` headers, based on the number of fields in the first data row and print those to `fn`.

Then, treat all lines like they are valid data lines( no comments ):

- Prepend a `t# OFS` to each data row and then print it to `fn`

I placed the awk script into a file `script.awk` and then `chmod +x script.awk`.

Given the following two input data files (`data1` and `data2`) in the same directory:

```
cat data1 data2
1,2 
3,4 
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

and running the script like `script.awk data*` gives the following two `.new` data files:

```
cat data1.new data2.new
,c1,c2
t1,1,2 
t2,3,4 
,c1,c2,c3
t1,1,2,3
t2,4,5,6
t3,7,8,9
```

As long as the file names are similar to each other and don't match the script's name, it should be easy to pass them all to the script.  I didn't anything to align the columns as the numbers increase in length, just enough to give one leading space to the `c#` row.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and the nice formatting. As you see I am still learning to format my question. When I do script.awk data* I get an error "script.awk: command not found". I did place the awk script into the script.awk file and the chmod command. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry.  I keep forgetting to prepend `./` to scripts in questions as I often use `csh`.  If you're using bash, try `./script.awk data*`.

Comment: Makes more sense. So I should do chmod +x script.awk followed by ./script.awk data* , correct? The second yields an error" (No such file or directory)". I can "ls" and see that script.awk is indeed an executable in the folder and so are data1 and data2..

Comment: What does `awk -f script.awk data*` do for you?

Comment: Cool. So now the .new files are generated, however the format I need (and the format you display in your answer) is not found in them. Instead data1.new looks as follows:
first line: " 1 2"
second line: blank
third line: " space c1 c2"
fourth line: "t1 3 4"

 c1 c2
t1 3 4

Comment: Ah - this is an issue of my understanding of the original file formatting.  You don't appear to have an empty line, or otherwise "non-data" line prior to the start of the data lines.

Comment: Sorry. Does the new formatting in the question help a bit?

Comment: I've updated your question with what I think you your formatting is: comma delimited, numerical data.  I've also edited my answer to reflect those changes.  That's all for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should show some code you have tired and if it doesn't work, you can ask the people on stack overflow, Most people here won't even help you without code. Here is an outline of what to do, you can implment it in your favorite programming language/environment

1. create a new **output** file
2. Open your existing **csv** file
3. Add your new rows to the top of the **output** file (c1 c2 c3..)
4. for each line in **csv**

   now we are trying to create each line in the **output** file

   a. split line using spaces (or some other delimiter)

   b. write t1 to **output** and insert delimiter

   c. write the 1st and 2nd "tokens" from your split

   d. write t2 to **output** and insert delimter

   e. write the remain columns to the line

   f. insert newline character in **output** file
5. close both **csv** and **output** file

optional "overwriting" the original csv

6. delete original **csv**
7. rename **output** file to your old **csv** file name

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
      FS=" "
      if (NR == 1) {
         printf ("%s", FS)
         for (col=1;col < NF;col++) printf( "c%d%s", col, FS)
         printf( "c%d\n", NF)
         }
     if ( $0 !~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ ) {
         printf ( "t%d%s%s\n", NR, FS, $0)
         }
     }' YourFile
```

- assume here (strange for a csv) that space is the separator, for any more traditionnal separator, just adapt the `FS=" "` with your separator value
- add your header column on first line
- add the `tX` start of line
- take 1st line as reference for number of column in header

add a `find ...` or batch loop to change it in every csv you have in your folder

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk 4.* for `-i inplace`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%sc%d%s",(i>1?"":OFS),i,(i<NF?OFS:ORS)
}
{ print "t" FNR, $0 }

$ cat file
1,2
3,4

$ awk -i inplace -f tst.awk file

$ cat file
,c1,c2
t1,1,2
t2,3,4
```

Just change `file` to `*` and it'll update every file in your directory.